# Knowledge needed to study and understand general and special relativity theory

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the prerequisites to studying general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/what-are-the-prerequisites-to-studying-general-relativity)

I'am 27 now and i have a burning desire to study math and physics from the ground up and I strongly prefer doing a self study.I want to be a self tutor till i reach certain level.

My question is what is the minimum knowledge needed to read and completely understand the General and Special Theory of Relativity.

As of now my level of math knowledge is basic differential calculus.I also have a basic understanding of Kinematics {One dimensional motion with constant acceleration}

I welcome all possible sugessions,advices and recomendations.

Thank's in Advance