# Learning General Relativity from a mathematical and physical point of view

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I am an undergraduate in Mathematics writing his dissertation on General Relativity this year. The next couple of months will be dedicated to learning the math (geometry) and the physics, and to this end I am looking for must-read/must-watch material on the topic.

General book recommendations are welcome, but keep in mind I can use Google! I am mainly looking for really good introductory content that I would have a hard time finding myself, whether it be videos, course notes, books or blog posts.

My apologies if this is a duplicate!

Comment: PS: I am aware of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14074/ , looking for some more material

Comment: [Carroll](https://www.amazon.com/Spacetime-Geometry-Introduction-General-Relativity/dp/0805387323) is how I learned. Recommend.

Comment: Susskind is the best http://bit.ly/1wtzsJW

Comment: For really rigorous mathematical treatment, nothing beats Barrett O'Neill's book [Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity](https://www.amazon.com/Semi-Riemannian-Geometry-Applications-Relativity-Mathematics/dp/0125267401) .